# Drag and drop ymapkit java

Tags: java, android-studio, yandex-maps-api

Как реализовать перемещение плейсмарка путем его перетаскивания? Нашел такую опцию как `setDraggable(boolean)`, поставил тру, но ничего не произошло
Заранее благодарю

Comment: [вот тут можно посмотреть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897409/how-does-one-implement-drag-and-drop-for-android-marker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если под **ymapkit** вы подразумеваете нативный [MapKit Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/), то действие верное – **mark.[setDraggable](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/map/MapObject.html?lang=ru#_11)(true);**

В [примере Яндекса](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yandex/mapkitdemo/MapObjectsActivity.java) метка так и задаётся:

```
    PlacemarkMapObject mark = mapObjects.addPlacemark(DRAGGABLE_PLACEMARK_CENTER);
    mark.setOpacity(0.5f);
    mark.setIcon(ImageProvider.fromResource(this, R.drawable.mark));
    mark.setDraggable(true);
```

Если речь идёт о каком-то другом МапКите, следует уточнить детали в самом вопросе, а также привести свой пример кода.